# Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]

Tags: spring

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] for property 'jdbcTemplate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Can you upload your configuration related codes?

Comment: thanx sir but i got the  solution